# Why would someone use int instead of bool data type?

Tags: c++, c, typedef

Recently I saw in one project where they typedef int as BOOL and used it in place of bool. Does doing so provides any advantages?

```
typedef int BOOL;
```

Comment: This has a lot of disadvantages, and no real benefits. If it's any version of a language where booleans exist, those should be used instead. This typedef means that you can have different true values not equal to each other.

Comment: Some people don't even bother to `typedef`.

Comment: C++ and C are two different languages.

Comment: Before `bool` was added to standard C it was fashionable to define your own. There's heaps of legacy code with it still. Cleaning it completely out is just never a priority.

Comment: No advantage at all. Better  #include <stdbool.h>

Comment: Fun anecdote: until recently `bool b = false; b++;` was legal - because obviously you can increment a `bool` like an `int` ;) Luckily we recently got rid of that. Compatibility and legacy concerns never fail to surprise and screw you over.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Still legal... it's just that `b` is casted back to `bool`, so you will get `1` even after many increments.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I can't check right now (on my phone), but I'm *fairly* sure that as of C++17 "bool increment" is no longer just deprecated, but actually invalid..

Comment: @JesperJuhl Oh.. I am talking about C.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Just goes to show that C and C++ are *very* different languages these days :)

Comment: One can do some funny tricks applying arithmetic and bitwise operators on (the standard) `bool` (in C). https://ideone.com/PrRY2D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193790/discussion-between-jesper-juhl-and-eugene-sh).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One might do so if they were interfacing a lot with C code. Since C does not have a `bool` type - at least not untill C11 (I think it was, or maybe C99) introduced the `_Bool` type - which I can't honestly remember if is compatible with C++ `bool` - they should have just adopted the `bool` keyword (IMHO), but I digress.

Also, it is common in old C++ code bases that pre-date the C++98 standard where C++ gained `bool`.

So *legacy* and *C compatibility* is the answer.

Comment: @melpomene I'll take your word on that. My memory of when `_Bool` was introduced is a bit fuzzy ;) it was a fair number of years ago.

Comment: I can give you a citation. :-) ISO 9899:1999, 6.2.5 Types, 2 "An object declared as type `_Bool` is large enough to store the values 0 and 1."

Comment: @melpomene Thanks :)

Comment: C didn't want to adopt `bool` because so much legacy code had already defined their own versions of `bool` and they didn't want to invalidate all of that code.  Instead, they made another type from a reserved namespace (that is, a name beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter).  They still made it really easy to use `bool` by just including `<stdbool.h>` if you weren't handcuffed by legacy code.  Seems like a reasonable compromise to me.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons the whole _ + capital == reserved name I know well enough and I can see why they did that. Not breaking old code also makes sense - somewhat. Sometimes you have to break eggs to make an omelet and C++ had already established `bool` as a keyword. So I *get* their reasons, but I just think that when looking towards the future (where *most* code is written) it would have made sense to make a clean break and just adopt `bool`. But, that's just *my* opinion and not what happened.

Comment: @JesperJuhl  It is not for the standards body to choose to break my eggs!  As a compiler vendor (who have seats in the standardisation committee), it would be commercially foolish to introduce changes that break your customer's existing code.  Moreover most of the code I am using now was written in the past (and none of it was written in the future!).  GCC has to compile the Linux code base, and VC++ Windows neither GNU nor Microsoft would needlessly break their own code bases.

Answer (score 1):

C did not have a dedicated Boolean type until the 1999 standard - any scalar with a non-zero value was considered "true", while a zero value was considered "false".  A common *convention* was to use macros and/or typedefs to create Boolean values:

```
#define BOOL int
#define TRUE (1)
#define FALSE (0)
```

or

```
typedef int bool;
static const bool true = 1;
static const bool false = 0;
```

or something similar.

So what you're looking at is either old (pre-C99) C code, or code written by someone who learned C before that standard came out.

Note that C still considers *any* non-zero scalar value to be "true", and control expressions in `if` and `for` and `while/do while` statements do not specifically have to have Boolean types.  Since it was derived from C, the same is true in C++, even though it also has dedicated Boolean types and operators.